# Having trouble solving second order linear odes where the coefficient of $y'$ is one (or zero)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having problems with this equation right here

$$xy'' - y' - 4x^2y = 0$$

If I try a substitution $y = \phi(x) \cdot z(x)$, I get another second order equation which is not more easily solvable than the first one.

In general, I have trouble solving these kinds of equations where the coefficient of $y'$ is zero or one.

Can anyone provide a hint into solving these kinds of exercises?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking for simplifying structures, here you can divide by $x^2$ to get
$$
\left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)'-4y=0.
$$
Now set $y'=x·z$ so that the equation reduces to $z'=4y$. This now is a first order system. Put them together the other way by eliminating $y$,
$$
z''=4y'=4xz.
$$
This is a scaled Airy equation, with solution in the Airy functions.